# Why is my number of workspaces stuck on 4 (gnome-shell installed into ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, gnome-shell

I can change the number of rows to display, but increasing the number of workspaces changes the number shown, but not the number of names in the name list, and then not the number shown in the applet, and then going back into the preferences after it shows 4 again.

Fresh install of ubuntu 11.10 plus apt-get install gnome-shell.

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/34578/20245 Here's one for Gnome, 10.04 runs gnome

Comment: You're right, and it looks like something really weird is going on on this system, because neither the ccsm change nor gconftool on the command line can change it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but changing from the 173 version of the nvidia drivers to the current version of the nvidia drivers fixed this problem.